# How to disable bluetooth auto-connect with my phone?

Tags: windows-7, windows, bluetooth, mobile-phone

My PC connects a paired smartphone whenever I reboot PC, and registers itself as headset. And that sucks, because connection drains phone's battery and I don't want to use my PC as headset. Any way to disable this auto-connect?
I've got CSR bluetooth dongle and use Windows' built-in drivers.

Comment: You need bluetooth headset that support HSP
http://www.bluetooth.com/English/Technology/Works/pages/hsp.aspx

Comment: As you'll have noticed, without the particular make and model of phone all you'll get is generic answers.  Please provide the make and model (and ideally firmware revision if you know it).

Comment: This issue exists for any paired bluetooth device under windows. There is no option to turn auto connect off, like JNK says in the comment under his answer. Super annoying but true. Even if you manually disconnect the phone, but leave them paired, if your windows goes into lockscreen or sleep or anything, it will autoconnect AGAIN after returning from lockscreen/sleep...

Comment: Related Q: [How do I keep my bluetooth headphones from connecting to my windows 10 machine when it's connected to my phone?](https://superuser.com/questions/1310471/)

Answer (score 1):

My current way of doing this seems to work part of the time but it is still the best I've found/come up with so far.

I used autohotkey to create a shortcut (ctrl shift alt b in my case) that disables the bluetooth handsfree // support service. I also created one to open up the sound settings window (ctrl shift alt d) so I can force connect/disconnect as needed. Here is the code (you must create an admin-access shortcut to the .bat as a .lnk file)

.bat:

> net stop DeviceAssociationService
>
> net stop bthserv
>
> net stop BthHFSrv

autohotkey (also disconnects top two audio devices in your list):

> ^!+b:: EnvGet, DROPBOX, DROPBOX ;not necessary - I just share
>   autohotkey scripts across computers and have dropbox stored in
>   different places hence the environment variable
>
> Run %DROPBOX%\Code\Services\utils\batcommands\bstop.lnk ;replace with
>   your .lnk address
>
> Run, mmsys.cpl  WinWait,Sound
>
> SetControlDelay -1
>
> ControlClick,X96 Y110,Sound,,R
>
> ControlSend,SysListView321,{Down 3}{ENTER}
>
> ControlClick,X96 Y160,Sound,,R ControlSend,SysListView321,{Down
>   3}{ENTER}
>
> ControlClick,OK return
>
> ^!+d:: Run, mmsys.cpl
>
> return

Answer (score 1):

***There is no way in windows (including windows 7, 8 and 10) to disable auto-connect for paired bluetooth devices.*** This answer applies to any bluetooth device, be it a phone or something other. You can only take manual action for every device use or for every system 'log in', depending on your preference:

- disconnect the bluetooth device after every log in (including from sleep, lockscreen, etc.)
- pair-unpair the bluetooth device for every use
- enable-disable the bluetooth device for every use
- enable-disable bluetooth alltogether for every use

So the answer is: **its impossible**. Basically what JNK says in the comment under his answer. Judging by how old all relevant forum posts to this are, this issue has existed for very long and continues to exist.

Two microsoft and a technet forum post discussing this:
[first ms,](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/win10-how-to-disconnect-a-bluetooth-device-without/99a66cc9-c715-4e8b-8410-aa6426a98e35) 
[second ms,](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/how-to-prevent-bluetooth-devices-from-auto/e950fd05-4608-4dbd-b3f2-115880210e39) 
[technet.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/217059f6-87cb-4563-a609-7025e1011f32/how-to-disable-bluetooth-autoconnect?forum=w7itprohardware)

Answer (score 0):

On most phones, you can diable auto-connect by letting it connect then removing the device from the bluetooth list once it is connected.

Comment: But I don't want to unpair these devices.

Comment: It's unpair or autoconnect for 99% of phones.

Comment: that can't be true... I never had problem with autoconnect on my previous system.

Comment: Was it a previous PC or a previous phone?

Comment: The same phone, other PC. And WinXP instead of Win7.

Answer (score 0):

What phone is this? On most phones, there's an option under the tools and settings menu to turn off bluetooth entirely.

Comment: I don't want to turn it off!!!! I use bluetooth, just don't want it to connect automatically.

Comment: But if it's on at all, it'll use power. Bluetooth power usage is all-or-nothing.

Comment: Bluetooth consumes (much) more energy, when it has a working connection (rather than just being turned on and idle)