# What is the difference between plugging in USB device and Enabling it in Windows

Tags: windows-10, usb, wireless-headset

What does Windows do differently when I plug a USB device in, comparing to when I have a disabled USB device (device manager) and I'm enabling it?
I want to apply a workaround for an issue with my PS4 Platinum Wireless Headset connected to Windows 10. USB dongle for this headset only starts looking for the Headset when I unplug and plug the dongle back in - it doesn't do that when I disable it in Device Manager, and enable it again. I also tried to use devcon.exe which comes with Windows Driver Kit - restarting, or disabling/enabling device using this tool doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Plugging, enabling and many other actions create events that are reported by Windows.
Some events gets reported to all executing processes, such a pending shutdown
request. Other events leave traces in the Windows Event Log.
Some Windows components and some third-party products listen to these events
and take action when they pertain to their domain.

In your case, (un)plugging a USB device and enabling/disabling it are separate
events, where one does not cause the other.
Evidently, the enabling/disabling event is not picked up by the Bluetooth
discovery service.

If you are enabling/disabling the device in order to stop it from auto-connecting
automatically when you boot, you might take a look at the post
[How do I keep my bluetooth headphones from connecting to my windows 10 machine when it's connected to my phone?](https://superuser.com/questions/1310471/how-do-i-keep-my-bluetooth-headphones-from-connecting-to-my-windows-10-machine-w),
where an alternate solution was to disable/enable the Bluetooth Support system service:

```
net stop bthserv
net start bthserv
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try to dig dipper into "Events world" and see if i can distinguish what happens when i plug the dongle in. PS4 Wireless Headset Use some other means of wireless communication instead of bluetooth, and comes with an USB dongle which communicate with the headset.