# Bluetooth toggle in Windows through AHK?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, autohotkey

I have spent the past two hours trying to turn off Bluetooth by a hotkey or through CMD.

This [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1310471/how-do-i-keep-my-bluetooth-headphones-from-connecting-to-my-windows-10-machine-w) shares two commands you can use to toggle Bluetooth:

```
net stop bthserv
net start bthserv
```

You get feedback saying it was successful but speaker still plays, mouse still works, etc etc.

Surely there is a way with AHK?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turn on/off Bluetooth radio/adapter from cmd/powershell in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1168551/turn-on-off-bluetooth-radio-adapter-from-cmd-powershell-in-windows-10)

Comment: No need to get huffy. You haven't figured something out, calling "incompetence" isn't necessary or helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this AHK script:

```
FileDelete, %A_Temp%\ServiceCheck.csv
RunWait, %comspec% /c "sc query bthserv" > %A_Temp%\ServiceCheck.csv
FileRead, Content, %A_Temp%\ServiceCheck.csv
    If InStr(Content, "STOPPED")
        Run, %comspec% /c "sc start bthserv"
    else
        Run, %comspec% /c "sc stop bthserv"
FileDelete, %A_Temp%\ServiceCheck.csv
```