# How to disable auto connection of bluetooth devices to my laptop?

Tags: windows-10

My laptop model is HP, whenever I **turn on** bluetooth in windows 10, all near by devices pair with my laptop without knowing my knowledge. Ex: Bluetooth hearphones.

I don't want my laptop OS to do that, so how to stop that?

Comment: Control Panel, Auto Play and make sure devices are set to choose. (All things).

Comment: I WANT auto-connect, but cannot achieve it!

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth works by pairing devices. Once pairing is confirmed, it automatically connects to one another when both devices are on. And you have to remove the pairing on your computer by deleting the audio device pairing:

Select Start > Settings > Devices > Bluetooth & other devices.
Select the paired Bluetooth device that you want to remove > Remove device

There is already similar discussion in below link and shared one way via command to disable/enable of the Bluetooth Support system service

net stop bthserv

net start bthserv

[How do I keep my bluetooth headphones from connecting to my windows 10 machine when it's connected to my phone?](https://superuser.com/questions/1310471/how-do-i-keep-my-bluetooth-headphones-from-connecting-to-my-windows-10-machine-w)