# How to manage Bluetooth autoconnect paired devices on Win11

Tags: windows-11, bluetooth

I would like to choose which Bluetooth device connects automatically and which does not.

I have many Bluetooth devices and for some I would like to use the automatic connection function, for example for my headphones, when I turn them on I would like them to connect automatically, but for other devices such as smart speakers, every time I turn on the PC they autoconnect, and in this case it is an unwanted function.
I would like all devices to remain paired to avoid having to repeat the pairing procedure for each device each time, but I want to choose which ones should connect automatically and which ones manually.

Is there a method or third party application that allows this?

Comment: Windows does not support this function, as far as I know. Have you done any research regarding this prior to asking here? Here are a few questions from this site which appear closely related: https://superuser.com/questions/1602622/how-to-disable-auto-connection-of-bluetooth-devices-to-my-laptop and https://superuser.com/questions/1310471/how-do-i-keep-my-bluetooth-headphones-from-connecting-to-my-windows-10-machine-w

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I keep my bluetooth headphones from connecting to my windows 10 machine when it's connected to my phone?](https://superuser.com/questions/1310471/how-do-i-keep-my-bluetooth-headphones-from-connecting-to-my-windows-10-machine-w)

Comment: Often this function is done in the App.  As noted not a Windows function.

Comment: If you disconnect them once, Windows will not attempt to reconnect automatically until you log in again/wake from sleep.